# Sticky footer is not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make simple page with sticky footer. Footer stick to the bottom but when there is a lot of content it goes behind sticky footer. Why?

```css
html, body{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#footer{
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"sticky footer"*? Always displayed at the bottom of page, even if the page needs a scrollbar? It's funny how so many people have answered and nobody cared to ask. Technically, there's no such thing as "*sticky footer*" and various people interpret this term differently. What ***exactly*** do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fixed` or `absolute` positioning along with `width`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well you can almost guarantee @mazenelzoor is downvoting for the sake of it for all of our answers.

Comment: This is bad because: 1. It creates a scrollbar even when the page doesn't have enough content. 2. It does not adapt to variable height of footer. This was ok 20 years ago, not now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `position:absolute` to create sticky footer. I recommend you to use flexbox. Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattonit/gpg89k5v/)

**Code Snippet:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Your Content goes here...</h2>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  This is sticky footer
</footer>
```

Comment: I would up-vote a solution that: doesn't create a scrollbar when not enough content. Keeps footer down at all times. Allows variable height of footer.

Comment: My solution doesn't create a scrollbar and I think it's better than using position:absolute

Comment: But, again, the main problem here is nobody cared to ask the OP what he means by sticky. If content should or should not push the footer down. Because that tends to be divided when asking different people what they mean by ***sticky footer***. Regarding *better*. There's no *better*. It's what the client wants. If they want something different, you can't force what you think is best on them. I hope you agree. I agree your solution is better UX. But maybe they don't want better UX. Maybe they want absolute positioned footer visible at all times. First thing to do: ask.

Answer (score -1):

What you have in your `code` is a `static footer` not `sticky` to make `sticky` do this.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is incomplete, at best, Oke.